# Split a long text for paginated display

Tags: java, angularjs, text, split, display

I'm building a website for a friend who's writing a novel, and want to display it, chapter by chapter, in a book-like display, with pages turning.

I have a frontend app in Angular 2 and a backend in Java (as they're the tools I'm more familiar with). A backoffice on the Angular app allows the user to add the text of a chapter, which is sent to the backend to be stored in the DB. Then the front of the Angular calls the backend to retrieve the chapter, and has to display it in the book-like display.

My problem is how can I split the text of the chapter into pages in order to display it. I could change the backoffice to force the user to add the text page by page. I could ask the user to put a specific marker in the text to indicate a page break. But I'ld like the process to be as transparent as possible for the user.

So I went for a solution by splitting the text on the backend. I estimated how many characters are on a line, and how many lines are on a page, then I cut the text accordingly (with some adjustments, as it's a HTML text with tags in it).
But it feels like a very strict approach, as I'm choosing the size of a page, regardless of the display interface size.

So I'm wondering if there is a better approach : 
- a different splitting algorithm
- a tool front-side to display my text without splitting it
- something else

Does anyone had to face a similar problem ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not so good with Angular, but regarding choosing the size of a page, if I was you, I definitely have some algorithm to determine the size of a page. Your backend should receive from frontend size of font etc and then calculate size of a page. I'm pretty sure that one of the future request will be to support changing of font size on frontend.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing that action on server side that has no sense of the page length.

I assume that a better approach shall be to get the complete chapter from backend to front end; and have a front end function that will calculate : 
- the number of characters per lines based on page size
- the number for line based on page size
- the number of chapter pages based on previous info

This is a way better approach than your full backend ones.

However; this is not a responsive approach.

**Do you have interest and need within a responsive one ?**

If yes; you may add a watch on the page length/height to recalculate the above values and re generated your pages

Comment: I do indeed need a responsive approach. So I will probably need to implement your solution.
The problem being : I'm not used to do it front-side, that's why I did it on the backend.
But the split of the chapter should be the responsibility of the frontend. I was wondering if there is any solution, method, tool, that does the job already

Comment: If you have difficulties on building your responsive approach; do not hesitate to post your code and difficulties. In the meanwhile; if my reply has helped you; do not hesitate to upvote ;)